# Set cache size for AVPlayer

Tags: ios, caching, avfoundation

Is it possible to simply set the size of the cache for an AVPlayer? I've an app where the user will often go back and forth in the video and I'd like to make sure that there's enough caching happening. I've found [that code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/83a93746d1ea52e9d23f) that shows how to manually handle the network requests using an `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` and that's pretty involved. Ideally I'm looking for something like

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
player.urlSession = myConfiguredURLSession
```